# Continue Main Looping In Nested For-each In XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

I am trying to do something that may seem irrational, but I have the reasons for such a request.

Hoped to create a nested for-each loop which will continue from the outer for-each or start over, as in the following example.

The following is the input xml, this input represents the structure I am working with, but with dummy data.
**XML:**

```
<table>
  <Row>
    <Field name="ver">1</field>
    <Field name="isNewVersion">1</field>
    <Field name="sub">a</field>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Field name="ver">1</field>
    <Field name="isNewVersion">0</field>
    <Field name="sub">b</field>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Field name="ver">1</field>
    <Field name="isNewVersion">0</field>
    <Field name="sub">c</field>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Field name="ver">2</field>
    <Field name="isNewVersion">1</field>
    <Field name="sub">x</field>
  </Row>
    <Row>
    <Field name="ver">2</field>
    <Field name="isNewVersion">0</field>
    <Field name="sub">y</field>
  </Row>
</table>
```

The outer for-each works fine, but can't seem to make the nested for-each to work. Is there a way to me it iterate over:

**The rest of the `<field>` tags (continue where it was left off by the outer for-each)**

*OR*

**Start from the beginning of the entire input xml**

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">

<Main>

    <xsl:for-each select="table/Row">
    
        <xsl:if select="field[@name='isNewVersion'] = 1">   <!--check if first sub per new version-->
        
            <Data ver="{field[@name='ver'}">
                
                <xsl:variable name="currentVer" select="{field[@name='ver'}" /> <!--saved for nested for-each-->                
                <xsl:for-each select="..."> <!--This is the problem, would like to iterate from the start of xml-->
                
                    <xsl:if select="{field[@name='ver'] = currentVer}"> <!--check if came to new version-->
                    
                        <Sub id="{field[@name='sub']}" />

                    </xsl:if>
                    
                </xsl:for-each>
                
            </Data>
        </xsl:if>
        
        
    </xsl:for-each>

</Main>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is how I would like the final (output) xml to look like.
**The Output I would like:**

```
<Main>
    <Data ver="1">
        <Sub id="a" />
        <Sub id="b" />
        <Sub id="c" />
    </Data>
    <Data ver="2">
        <Sub id="x" />
        <Sub id="y" />
    </Data>
</Main>
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: You're describing what you want to achieve in very procedural terms, and you're making your life difficult as a result. Don't think in terms of loops, of "starting over" and "leaving off" and "continuing". Think in terms of mappings: how do sets of things in the output relate (functionally) to sets of things in the input.

Comment: Having said that, this is actually a simple grouping problem, and knowing that, you can find masses of information about how to solve grouping problems in XSLT. It's much easier in XSLT 2.0+ than in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Because grouping questions are so common (despite the fact that people often don't recognise them as such), I'm closing this as a duplicate of one of the more popular questions/answers on grouping.

Comment: This is not exactly a grouping question. The records are already grouped in the sense that there is a distinct and recognizable "leader" record for each group. All that remains is to gather the records belonging to the current group.

Comment: Thanks both @MichaelKay and michael.hor257k, I did fail to recognize this indeed simple grouping problem, I also didn't mention that I can only use XSLT 1.0.
But, I did solve the problem algorithmically, with a nested loop and a variable, just iterated over the same xpath from the outer loop. This solution though, is wrong, and I'll change it to better suit the XSLT paradigm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="row-by-ver" match="Row" use="field[@name='ver']" />

<xsl:template match="/table">
    <Main>
        <xsl:for-each select="Row[field[@name='isNewVersion'] = 1]">
            <xsl:variable name="version" select="field[@name='ver']" />
            <Data ver="{$version}">
                <xsl:for-each select="key('row-by-ver', $version)">
                    <Sub id="{field[@name='sub']}" />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Data>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Main>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Note**:

XML is case-sensitive. `field` is not the same as `Field` and your input will produce an error on every line of:

```
<Field name="x">y</field>
```